# Belonging to the same connected component of a semialgebraic set

Tags: algebraic-topology, connectedness, real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

Warm-up and main questions:

1. Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a semialgebraic set and $x_1, x_2 \in X$. How can I effectively check if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are in the same connected component of $X$?
2. Let $f \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ be a multivariable polynomial. Let $X_1, X_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an algebraic curves with parametrisation at infinity $g_1, g_2$ respectivly ($g_1:[0,\infty)\to X_1$, $\lim_{t\to\infty}|g_1(t)|=+\infty $, $g_2:[0,\infty)\to X_2$, $\lim_{t\to\infty}|g_2(t)|=+\infty $ ). Assume that
   $$\lim_{t\to\infty}(f(g_1(t))=\lim_{t\to\infty}(f(g_2(t))=0.$$
   How can I check if $g_1([R,\infty))$ and $g_2([R,\infty))$ are in the same connected component of the set $f^{-1}((-\varepsilon, \varepsilon))$ (for $\varepsilon>0$ small enough, $R>0$ big enough)?

Comment: Take a look at chapter 16 of [Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted3.pdf) [PDF].

Comment: Thank you for the replay. Could you give me some more details how to attempt this problems? I'm not familliar with the book and it's seems overwhelming at first.

Comment: It's overwhelming to me, too.